# An object which was initially at rest explodes in three pieces. Is it necessary that all the pieces will be in same plane and not in 3 dimensions?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, vectors

I found this question in a test paper and the answer was all the three pieces must be in same plane because three vectors must be in same plane to cancel each other but if we consider a case like this-If three vectors such as i+j, k-j, -i-k are the velocities of the three pieces and all the pieces have same mass then won't the momentum cancel each other and the momentum conservation would be valid, and as of centre of mass it was initially at rest and is at rest even after the explosion. Is this scenario possible if not then why? If this case is possible then isn't the solution inaccurate as there is one single possibility where the particles can lie in three dimensions after explosion

Comment: Note that three vectors summing to zero have to lie in a plane no matter what.

Comment: Can you please explain as the three vectors in the hypothetical case sum up to zero

Comment: Things to think about. You are on the right track to think about conservation of momentum. The pieces exert equal and opposite forces on each other, same mass or not. Conservation of momentum says if the center of mass was at rest before the explosion, it will be at rest afterward. Three objects always lie in a plane. Why will the center of mass be in that plane? Why are the velocity vectors in that plane?

Comment: Under certain circumstances the 3 pieces could be contained within an infinite number of planes...

Comment: For any three distinct points in 3D space, there must always be at least one plane that contains all three of them. The fact that the three points happen to be the instantaneous locations of three fragments that "exploded" doesn't add anything to that.

Comment: It can be mathematically proved that 3 vectors must in the same plane in order to have a null resultant. Ask on mathematics SE to prove this and I will answer it to you there.

Comment: The example you provided is not correct. Those 3 vectors are coplanar as their scalar triple product is zero.